# CLASSIC asp connecting to SQL Express Server 500 server error

Tags: database, asp-classic, adodb, recordset

Hey all i am trying to get a connection to my SQL server version 10.50.2500 in **Classic ASP**

My code in the .asp page is (including all connection strings I've tried using):

```
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRS   = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'objConn.ConnectionString = "Provider={SQL Server};Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\SQLEXPRESS;Database=JForm;User ID=xxxx;Pwd=xxxx"
'objConn.ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\SQLEXPRESS;Database=JForm;Uid=xxxx;Pwd=xxxx;"
'objConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,1433;Database=JForm;Uid=xxxx;Pwd=xxxx;Persist Security Info=True"
'objConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI;Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=JForm;Uid=xxxx;Pwd=xxxx"
objConn.ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\SQLEXPRESS;Database=JForm;Uid=xxxx;Pwd=xxxx"

strSQL = "UPDATE jURLS " & _
        "SET rssFeedURL = 'http://www.xxxx.com/rss/" & rss & "'," & _
        "csvURL = 'http://www.xxxx.com/csv/" & csv & "'," & _
        "jFormName = '" & forname & "'," & _
        "isActive = " & active & " " & _
        "WHERE jFormName = '" & forname & "'"

objConn.open
objRS.Open strSQL, objConn, 1,3

'If Not objRS.EOF Then
 'iterate through records here
'Else
 'no records found
'End If

objRS.close
Set objRS=Nothing
objConn.close
Set objConn=Nothing
```

It seems to crash on the **objConn.open**. However, it only gives me a **500 - Internal server error.** and not an error thats helpful!

Once i take the database code from the page and leave everything else, it works without the **500 - Internal server error** being displayed.

What else can i try in order to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an extra comma here :

```
"isActive = " & active & "," & _
```

change it to:

```
"isActive = " & active & " " & _
```

about the connection error, [try debugging using the connection.errors collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
On Error Resume Next
objConn.open

for each errobj in objConn.Errors
    Response.write errobj.Number & "<br />"
    Response.write errobj.Description & "<br />"
next

On Error Goto 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. I believe it had to do with the server not being configured correctly in order for it to connect to the db server.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
response.write(strSQL) <-- this will allow you to look at your current SQL statement and see if it makes sense.
set objRS = objConn.execute(strSQL)
```

Comment: i don't get to see anything due to the page being 500.

Comment: Comment-out the execution line and look at your SQL. If you are using IE, go into the settings and turn off "friendly http error messages".

Comment: The query is good. However, it crashes on the **set objRS = objConn.execute(strSQL)** line.

Comment: Paste the query into an MS SQL query window directly, see if it actually executes or fails.

Comment: i get **(0 row(s) affected)** when running that in SQL manager. No errors.

Comment: (stupid me) There is no returned recordset, it's an UPDATE, so it's simply: *objConn.execute(strSQL)*, with no recordset assignment. You can get rid of all the *objRS* code.

Comment: Thanks for your post. I believe it had to do with the server not being configured correctly in order for it to connect to the db server.